# Why are GroupCollection and MatchCollection non-generic?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

When you want a group of regex matches in c#, you get a `MatchCollection`. Same deal with a group of groups and a `GroupCollection`.

However, they are both non-generic, even in 4.5, even though it would (as far as I know):

- Not break anything, at all, as `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`.
- Make it easier to use with LINQ, e.g. instead of `myMatchCollection.Cast<Match>().SomeLINQMethod()` you could just do `myMatchCollection.SomeLINQMethod()`
- Make it more efficient, as you don't need to cast it to start off with.
- Not be too much work for the team at all. All they need to do is change their internal implementation from an `ArrayList` to a `List<Match`||`Group>` (hell, even something like a `Match[]`||`Group[]`) and add a `Match GetEnumerator` method, which should take no more than 5 minutes.

My question here, though, is: am I missing something? Is there another reason why they can't change them to be generic, and far better to use with LINQ?

Comment: So far as I know, none of the non-generic API in .NET was changed when generics were introduced. It'd sure be nice, but I think making any change to the API would break binary compatibility at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

1. Changing the existing definitions would be a breaking change.
2. Every new feature incurs an opportunity cost that precludes implementing some other, possibly higher-value feature.
3. Perceived benefit is (very!?) minor.
4. Writing your own generic wrapper around the existing implementations is straight-forward.

If you disagree with any of these arguments, present the business case to Microsoft that they have miscalculated the benefit-cost determination. They might even listen, and implement it; what do you have to lose?

Comment: Sorry, how would changing the definition be a breaking change?

Comment: @ofstream, at its simplest, it could break anyone who depends on the API as it presently exists in a way that would be inconsistent with making the classes generic. If your code that worked before no longer works now, then it was certainly a breaking change as far as you are concerned. It could be something as simple as depending on the class exactly, for example. For more reading on it, you might find [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change.aspx) educational.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, so making `List<T>` implement `IReadonlyCollection<T>`, or making `T[]` implement `IEnumerable<T>` counts as breaking change?

Comment: @penartur: All changes must be assumed to be breaking changes, until proven otherwise. If you enumerate all use-cases and demonstrate how all of them are unaffected by the change then Microsoft might be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

> Not break anything, at all, as IEnumerable inherits from IEnumerable.

Probably not. It's true though that every change is a breaking change, in that there is always the risk of some weird interaction happening. The only way to absolutely guarantee no breaking changes is to not change anything.

While that isn't acceptable either (or there'd be no progress made in anything) it is a constant pressure against any change.

> Make it easier to use with LINQ, e.g. instead of myMatchCollection.Cast().SomeLINQMethod() you could just do myMatchCollection.SomeLINQMethod()

True, and a reason why on balance I think it would probably be worth doing. Note though that there were a couple of framework versions in between changing to generic being possible, and linq existing. I'll come back to this point.

> Make it more efficient, as you don't need to cast it to start off with.

You don't need to cast with many uses of MatchCollection, only if you are using it via an interface.

> Not be too much work for the team at all. All they need to do is change their internal implementation from an ArrayList to a List (hell, even something like a Match[]||Group[]) and add a Match GetEnumerator method, which should take no more than 5 minutes.

This change was done in the future branch (that is, additions to the API rather than fixes, added tests for existing code, etc.) of .NET Core as you can see at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/9a764c6fc139dbd3f3a526ad7def52178f1c71c3 There are 1,168 additions and 88 deletions, which is more than 5 minutes work, even if there was no review of it (which of course there was).

Note that there was no need to change from `ArrayList` to `List<Match>` and `List<Group>` because this had been already done.

And if it's pulled from future into master it will indeed bring some of the benefits you talk about.

But it's worth noting that even currently, if you iterate through `MatchCollection` you won't be casting (the internal code may or may not be, depending on the version you are using, as .NET Core and Silverlight both already use `List<Match>` internally while the others don't). If you are pushed into casting the cast is a relatively cheap one (unlike if the contained elements were value types).

At that point it was decided not to be worth the relatively mild risk for the relatively mild gain, especially considering everyone involved would have had other things to do.

At https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/271 it was decided that the gain was indeed worth the risk. Note that just discussing that risk involved more than five minutes work for the people involved.

Note also that enumeration isn't speeded as much as you might like in a bare `foreach` because the public `GetEnumerable()` still returns `IEnumerator` not `IEnumerator<Match>` as changing that would indeed have been a breaking change.